# Pyinstaller not working in Gitlab CI file

Tags: python, macos, gitlab, pyinstaller

I have created a python application and I would to deploy it via Gitlab. To achieve this, I create the following gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official language image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/
image: "python:3.10"
#commands to run in the Docker container before starting each job.
before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# different stages in the pipeline
stages:
  - Static Analysis
  - Test
  - Deploy
#defines the job in Static Analysis
pylint:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - pylint -d C0301 src/*.py

#tests the code
pytest:
  stage: Test
  script:
  - cd test/;pytest -v

#deploy
deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  script:
  - echo "test ms deploy"
  - cd src/
  - pyinstaller -F gui.py --noconsole
  tags:
  - macos
```

It runs fine through the Static Analysis and Test phases, but in Deploy I get the following error:

```
OSError: Python library not found: .Python, libpython3.10.dylib, Python3, Python, libpython3.10m.dylib
    This means your Python installation does not come with proper shared library files.
    This usually happens due to missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of the Python installation.
    * On Debian/Ubuntu, you need to install Python development packages:
      * apt-get install python3-dev
      * apt-get install python-dev
    * If you are building Python by yourself, rebuild with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on macOS).
```

As I am working on a Macbook I tried with the following addition `- env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.10.5` but then I get an error that python 3.10.5 already exists.

I tried some other things, but I am a bit stuck. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: have you tried adding the

```cmd
apt-get install python3-dev && apt-get install python-dev
``` 
to the pipeline?